# Problems using embedded Python in a C++ application

Tags: python, c++

I'm trying to embed Python in my C++ application, somewhat akin to the method found here in section 1.4:

https://docs.python.org/3.5/extending/embedding.html

The synopsis of the problem I'm having is that I can't get the C++ application to work with .py files that import the 'emb' module, ie, the Python extension module that's written into the C++ code.

I have a Python file, testmod.py:

```
import emb

# define some functions
def printhello(input):
    emb.numargs()
    return 2

def timesfour(input):
     print(input * 4)
```

In my C++ application, I have this code which works:

```
PyImport_AppendInittab("emb", &(mynamespace::PyInit_emb) );
Py_Initialize();

PyObject *globals = PyModule_GetDict(PyImport_AddModule("__main__"));

PyObject *testModule = PyImport_ImportModule("emb");
PyObject* pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(testModule, "numargs");
```

After this, pFunc is non-NULL; things look good. So I think the 'embedded module' is fine.

If I change the last two lines from above to:

```
PyObject* testModule = PyImport_ImportModule("testmod");
PyObject* pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(testModule, "printhello");
```

This also works fine, **provided the line emb.numargs() is removed from testmod.py** Once I add that line, and re-run the C++ application, testModule becomes NULL, which means something has gone wrong.

Any ideas?
Is this the way this capability is supposed to be used?

Comment: Does python have any way to communicate the actual error back to you? Systems usually can do this.

Comment: Wow, I'm an idiot, thanks for your suggestion.

I just had an indentation error in the line emb.numargs().  I guess that's what I get for switching between the languages all day. FWIW, I used PyErr_Print() to print the error.

Comment: That's why I hate python and avoid it. )))